# 2003 Mit. Galant, 2.4, Electrical issues

Tags: mitsubishi, wiring-diagram, galant

working on Horn, cruise control and signal wire to starter short to ground, plus it has a rough idle,, looking for a wiring diagram so I can trouble shoot this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!